# Why CATCH block allows the transaction to commit in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, sql-server-2012, try-catch

Recently, I encountered an SQL error due to the following statement in our legacy code. It tries to drop a temp table, and move on if it hasn't been defined. Clearly, it's a bad way to check the existence of a temp table, but that's not my question here.

```
BEGIN TRY 
    DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 

END CATCH
```

The statement runs fine (without any error) as is, but as soon as you put it in a Begin Tran/Commit Tran block like the following, the behavior becomes interesting.

```
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY 
        DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 

    END CATCH 
COMMIT TRAN
```

My understanding is that Try..Catch block doesn't affect Transactions - once it goes into the Catch block, the transaction will be in an uncommittable state, and the transaction will be rolled back, and that's what I see on SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0. When it's executed inside a Begin Tran/Commit Tran block, we will get an error:

```
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
```

However, it runs without any error on SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0. The XACT_STATE() returns 1 after the END CATCH line. The transaction will be committed, and if there are other data changes before and after the DROP TABLE statement, the changes will stay.

```
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY 
        DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 

    END CATCH 
    PRINT XACT_STATE()
COMMIT TRAN
```

In all these tests, I've made sure XACT_ABORT is OFF. So my question is what will cause this behavior difference. Is it truly a different between 2008 R2 and 2012, or it's some server/DB settings controlling how Try...Catch block and Transaction work.

---

**Edit 1**: I tried to run the following script on both 2008 R2 and 2012 instances. I also tried putting the INSERT dbo.UserOptionsLog line in different places, before the Begin Tran, after the Begin Try, after the Begin Catch, after the the commit tran, but it doesn't change the results.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'UserOptionsLog')
    CREATE TABLE dbo.UserOptionsLog([Set Option] SYSNAME, [Value] VARCHAR(100), ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL)


BEGIN TRAN
    DELETE FROM dbo.UserOptionsLog
    INSERT dbo.UserOptionsLog EXEC('DBCC USEROPTIONS')
    SELECT * FROM dbo.UserOptionsLog

    BEGIN TRY 

        DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 

    END CATCH 
COMMIT TRAN
```

Results from 2008 R2 instance.

```
Set Option  Value   ID
textsize    2147483647  40
language    us_english  41
dateformat  mdy 42
datefirst   7   43
lock_timeout    -1  44
quoted_identifier   SET 45
arithabort  SET 46
ansi_null_dflt_on   SET 47
ansi_warnings   SET 48
ansi_padding    SET 49
ansi_nulls  SET 50
concat_null_yields_null SET 51
isolation level read committed  52
```

Messages from 2008 R2 instance

```
(0 row(s) affected)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

(13 row(s) affected)

(13 row(s) affected)
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
```

Results from 2012 instance.

```
Set Option  Value   ID
textsize    2147483647  53
language    us_english  54
dateformat  mdy 55
datefirst   7   56
lock_timeout    -1  57
quoted_identifier   SET 58
arithabort  SET 59
ansi_null_dflt_on   SET 60
ansi_warnings   SET 61
ansi_padding    SET 62
ansi_nulls  SET 63
concat_null_yields_null SET 64
isolation level read committed  65
```

Messages from 2012 instance.

```
(13 row(s) affected)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

(13 row(s) affected)

(13 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: SQL Servers error handling is complete garbage. It is entirely unpredictable whether an error rolls back, does nothing or dooms the transaction. Fyi.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/740673

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the link.  It's quite confusing as far as how it will behave and there is no documentation describing this change in SQL Server 2012. However, I actually like the way 2012 works, because when I use an empty catch block, I really expect it to move on without consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...]and that's what I see on SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0.
>   When it's executed inside a Begin Tran/Commit Tran block, we will get
>   an error:
>
> Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 The current transaction cannot be
>   committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file.
>   Roll back the transaction. Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The
>   transaction is rolled back. However, it runs without any error on SQL
>   Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0. [...]

I believe the reason for this diff. behavior is the value of `XACT_ABORT` setting.

When `OFF` then `XACT_STATE()` returns `1`, TX is commitable and `COMMIT TRAN` is executing without errors:

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY 
        DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 

    END CATCH 
    PRINT XACT_STATE()
COMMIT TRAN
```

but when is `ON`

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY 
        DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 

    END CATCH 
    PRINT XACT_STATE()
COMMIT TRAN
```

because of error/exception intercepted by `CATCH` block, TX becomes domed/uncommitable (`-1`) and `COMMIT TRAN` raise another error/exception:

```
-1
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

**Update:**

I reproduced reported behaviour on SQL2008R2. On 2008R2, it seems that no matter what value has XACT_ABORT (ON/OFF), TX becomes uncommitable. SQL2012 changed this behaviour thus: TX becomes uncommitable only when XACT_ABORT is ON.

Comment: That's my first thought as well, but I've made sure XACT_ABORT is OFF in all my tests.  I was running the following line right after Begin Tran line, and I got 'XACT_ABORT OFF' all the time.
IF ( (16384 & @@OPTIONS) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT ON' ELSE PRINT 'XACT_ABORT OFF'

Comment: Try using `DBCC USEROPTIONS`. `CREATE TABLE dbo.UserOptionsLog([Set Option] SYSNAME, [Value] VARCHAR(100), ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL)
INSERT dbo.UserOptionsLog
EXEC('DBCC USEROPTIONS')`

Comment: This is what I got on the SQL 2012 instance where the transaction commits fine.

Set Option Value ID
textsize 2147483647 1
language us_english 2
dateformat mdy 3
datefirst 7 4
lock_timeout -1 5
quoted_identifier SET 6
arithabort SET 7
ansi_null_dflt_on SET 8
ansi_warnings SET 9
ansi_padding SET 10
ansi_nulls SET 11
concat_null_yields_null SET 12
isolation level read committed 13

Comment: Please use `BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT TRAN; INSERT ... EXEC('DBCC USEROPTIONS');`, If there is a line for `xact_abort` then it should be `ON`.

Comment: I did `Begin tran INSERT dbo.UserOptionsLog EXEC('DBCC USEROPTIONS') commit tran select * from dbo.UserOptionsLog`
but got the same results

Comment: I also tried `Begin tran
DROP TABLE #my_temp_table
commit tran
INSERT dbo.UserOptionsLog EXEC('DBCC USEROPTIONS')
select * from dbo.UserOptionsLog`, but didn't see xact_abort in the results.

Comment: This means that is OFF.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't run the script on the right server.  I just ran it on the 2008 instance, and didn't see xact_abort which means it's OFF. It shouldn't cause any error, but I got the error mentioned earlier.

Comment: Could you please update the answer with output of DBCC USEROPTIONS and also with the result: error or not for **both instances** ?

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this.  I just added additional information on the original post.

Comment: @G.S.: On both instances, SQL are the same settings. I reproduced reported behaviour on SQL2008R2. On 2008R2, it seems that no matter what value has XACT_ABORT (ON/OFF), TX becomes uncommitable. SQL2012 changed this behaviour thus: TX becomes uncommitable only when XACT_ABORT is ON.

Comment: thanks for confirming that.  I looked at the TRY...CATCH on [MSDN for 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.110).aspx) , but there is no mentioning of such behavior difference.  Have you found any documentation on this?

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I will keep this open for a little longer, and see if anyone else has any insight on this.